# xib with UICollectionView - not key value coding compliant

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, xib

I have a Custom `UIView` with an XIB. This custom `UIView` has a `UICollectionView` which is connected to an `IBOutlet`. In the view setup, the `UICollectionView` is initialised properly and is not nil.

However in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method, I get this error:-

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key selectorCollectionView.'

If I remove the datasource and delegate, I do not get any error. If I add them  Iget an error at this line:-

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "selectorCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectorCell
```

Please help!

Edit: I have attached screenshots of my setup

[image: The custom view is added to a UITableViewCell]

[image: The custom view has this collectionview]

[image: I have set the class for the cell]

[image: and the identifier]

I have uploaded the project here too http://www.fast-files.com/getfile.aspx?file=148623

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a sync issue. Happens sometimes:

1. Try cut outlets loose and reconnect them.
2. Make sure Collection Reusable View identifier is defined in xib file:
   [image: Set identifier here]
3. Make sure collection-view cell's custom class is define in xib file:

[image: Set custom class here]

**EDIT:**
I dug into your project and here are my findings

UICollectionView should be init' in `awakeFromNib` method (override it):

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: "SelectorCell"), bundle: nil)
    selectorCollectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "selectorCell")
    selectorCollectionView.dataSource = self
    selectorCollectionView.delegate = self
}
```

loadViewFromNib should be looking like this (Remove collection view init'):

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "SelectorView", bundle: nil)
    let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
    return view
}
```

Subclass SelectorTableViewCell likewise.

```
class SelectorTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var selectorView: SelectorView!
}
```

In `Main.storyboard` - custom class `UITableViewCell` to `SelectorTableViewCell` and connect `SelectorView` inside `contentView` to 'SelectorTableViewCell''s outlet.

That's it i think. [Here](https://ufile.io/m2wt0) is the project:

Comment: thanks for the reply Daniel, I tried that several times and even quit Xcode, deleted derived data and all that bullshit. I am editing the question with my screenshots

Comment: Challenging :-)
Maybe you have referenced subclass of UIView in your xib file that isn't connected properly. This happens when your xib reference a wrong class. 
If you haven't removed that referenced .swift and .xib files - i suggest you do and re-add them. Maybe also, delete identifier and class (2,3) and restate them.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I will try that. I have also uploaded the project in my question. Would be awesome if you could have a look :)

Comment: @RajeevBhatia, I edited my answer with a solution. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @RajeevBhatia - Your project is attached at the end of my answer. Your issue was resolved. Please accept the answer.

Comment: For what it's worth. I didn't notice "Inherit Module from Target" wasn't enabled and that fixed my problem. Could be worth a second check.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

1. Click on **File Owner** at the left panel of `YourCell.xib`. Then go to **Attributes inspector** and check whether there is any class specified in **Class** field. If not - no help from me here. If yes - remove it and tap *Enter*.
2. In `YourCell.xib` sequentially click on all subviews and delete all the outlets in **Connections Inspector**. No need to delete them in `YourCell.swift`.
3. Once your cell's **File Owner** and outlets are removed, we're ready to reconnect the outlets. Just drag every one as usually to an existing corresponding IBOutlet in `YourCell.swift`.

As a result, when you click on **YourCell** at the left panel of `YourCell.xib` and go to **Connections Inspector**, you'll see there are all the outlets connected. Like so:

[image]

And if you check connections for a particular view in **YourCell**, you should see that it's outlet is connected to **YourCell** (**StaticSlot** in my case).

[image]

This helped me and hope you'll get the same.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, the problem was making the wrong connection in Storyboard. Click on the custom class in Storyboard -- not the File Owner -- then connect the IB outlet to the variable in the custom class.

Answer (score 0):

if try to register you custom class and cell ID

```
self.collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
self.collectionView.register(CustomClassCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```